# Get timeout error in magento on reindexing in the admin

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, timeout, execution

Hi i am getting the **maximum timeout error** in the **magento** admin on **reindexing** the data How can i fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP configuration increase max_execution_time value.

You can do this in code: set_time_limit(0) - this completely disables time limit.

Comment: is there any limit of value ?

Comment: PHP manual does not mention any limits.

Comment: ok hope setting 0 will work

Comment: setting the timeout to 0 is a really bad idea. If you are in a loop your server will run out of memory and cpu. Set it high, but don't disable it.

Comment: @Fabian I use setting 0 for years without problems, have some scripted tasks which can run for very long time. It's up to you how well written script is. Endless loop is a bug. Leaked memory probems I saw only once when parsed long XML but anyway managed to fix those.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways of solving this.

Method 1 - using php

```
set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Method 2

change the max_execution_time in my php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 1000
```

Remember to restart the server

If you have any issues let me know